# How to label missing values in python using loop

Tags: python, missing-data, fillna

this is my Dataframe

```
from cmath import nan


student_card = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[20190103, 20190222, 20190531],
                             'name':['Kim', nan, nan],
                             'class':['H', 'W', 'S']})
student_card
```

it looks like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWMcZ.png)

so there are two NaN values in 'name' columns, and I want to fill them as 'missing1', 'missing2' using loop (idk not using loop but have no idea how to index them without loop)

so I made this function and got stuck over here. It doesn't work
please give me some helps, thanks

```
import pandas as pd

def fillna_func(df):
    df = df.copy()
    for i, value in enumerate(df.values):
        if value == nan:
            df[i].apply("deleted{}".format(i))
    return df


fillna_func(student_card['name'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a mask where the name is null, and filter the main dataframe by that.  Then update those names using using the cumulative sum of the missing values.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
student_card = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[20190103, 20190222, 20190531],
                             'name':['Kim', np.nan, np.nan],
                             'class':['H', 'W', 'S']})

def fillna_func(df):
    m = df.name.isnull()
    df.loc[m, 'name'] = 'missing' + m.cumsum().astype(str)
    return df

fillna_func(student_card)
```

Output

```
         ID      name class
0  20190103       Kim     H
1  20190222  missing1     W
2  20190531  missing2     S
```